'event' is deprecated.ts(6385)
So I'm currently having issues getting around this 'event', from what I've currently read i need to pass it through an event handler function as when used in external JS 'event' is for windows.event.
var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-links");
var tabcontents = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-contents");
function opentab(tabname) {
    for (tablink of tablinks) {
        tablink.classList.remove("active-link")
    }
    for (tabcontent of tabcontents) {
        tabcontent.classList.remove("active-tab");
    }
    event.currentTarget.classList.add("active-link");
    document.getElementById(tabname).classList.add("active-tab");
}

Something along the lines of..
tablink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    opentab(event, 'active-tab');

Would someone care to break this down for me?
Appreciate it.
Attempted to replace the code using event handler.

so, you call opentab(event, 'active-tab'); ... but opentab only expects a single argument ... can you see the issue?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

dejavu, I've just seen this question before. Joke aside I remember seeing you asked this question yesterday, did you not understand the answers and comments?

Modify the opentab function to accept the event parameter:
function opentab(event, tabname) {
    for (let tablink of tablinks) {
        tablink.classList.remove("active-link");
    }
    for (let tabcontent of tabcontents) {
        tabcontent.classList.remove("active-tab");
    }
    event.currentTarget.classList.add("active-link");
    document.getElementById(tabname).classList.add("active-tab");
}

